# Suspense equivalent for QML

Tags: reactjs, qt, qml

React has a concept of delaying a component render for when
its dependencies are ready, named [`Suspense`](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/Suspense)

In QML what would be the equivalent / alternative?

The rather naive approach would be to use a `Loader`  in a component [like this](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

```js
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Pane {id:root
    property bool completed: false
    property var network_data: {'hello': 'world'}
    Timer {id:timer
        interval: 500;
        onTriggered: root.completed = true
    }  
    Button{
        text: 'fetch'
        onClicked: timer.start()
    }
    Suspense{
        width: 200; height: 200;
        anchors.centerIn: parent;
        test: root.completed
        fallback: Loading{}
        delegate: NeedsNetworkData{network_data: root.network_data}
    }
}

// Loading.qml
import QtQuick
AnimatedImage{
    anchors.centerIn: parent;
    source: "https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.behance.net/project_modules/disp/04de2e31234507.564a1d23645bf.gif"
}

// NeedsNetworkData.qml
import QtQuick

Rectangle{
    required property var network_data
    color: "grey"
    Text{
        anchors.centerIn:parent;
        text: JSON.stringify(network_data.hello)
    }
}


// Suspense.qml
import QtQuick

Loader {
    id: root
    required property bool test
    required property Component fallback
    required property Component delegate
    
    sourceComponent: test? delegate: fallback
}
```

However I seek for a better solution for

1. I instantiated the component here:

```js
delegate: NeedsNetworkData{network_data: root.network_data}
```

2. React has no `delegate` property you just dump what ever component you want (that is 'Suspenseable') inside the Suspense component, i.e:

```js
<Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
  <Biography />
  <Panel>
    <Albums />
  </Panel>
</Suspense>
```

3. In react you don't need to have the `test` property I used above.

EDIT:
It seems from the comments that it isn't clear enough, the goal of suspense is to **delay initialization** of the component that depends on the (not arrived yet) data in order to avoid null-checks **while sustaining the declarative style of the language.**
i.e:

```js
Text{
    text: data.field.otherfield
}
```

without suspense would look like

```js
Text{
    text: data? data.field.otherfield: ""  
}
```

UPDATE:
I created a QTBUG you can [track it here](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-111344#anchor).

Comment: I guess that some item replacement switched on `Loader.Ready` with an actual one will absolutely fit your needs

Comment: @folibis I am not sure I understand. can you clarify?

Comment: Unfortunately, your example isn't that good. In your scenario, `NeedsNetworkData` will not be constructed unless the test is set to true; therefore, the `Loader` has no idea whether or not your data has been loaded. (*Considering if `NeedsNetworkData` is responsible for loading its own data*)
I think you shouldn't use a `Loader`; instead, check if data is loaded and then only update its visibility.
Also, there are lots of other things you can do, but you first need to clarify your situation.

Comment: @SMR The thing is that if `NeedsNetworkData` is instantiated (or fetches is own data) you would need to have many null-checks and this gets ugly very quickly. settings `visible` to `false` is not enough.

Comment: In QML, if your activities are related to animation, you have https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-pauseanimation.html otherwise, you have Promises and Promise chaining. Since you come from React, you ought to be familiar with the latter.

Comment: @StephenQuan Can you explain how `PauseAnimation` can help here? About promises, AFAIK there is no QML support for promises and if there were you would need to imperatively create components.

Comment: @ניר the bigger picture is SequentialAnimation and ParallelAnimation. None, of which, are related to the waiting for a property change, such as asynchronous load, but, the scheduling of parallel and sequential activities can be orchestrated with PauseAnimation. With the Promises comment, Promises is supported in QML. I have an app in the Google Play store that demonstrates that with the source code here https://github.com/stephenquan/qt5-qml-promises-demo

Comment: If we assume that *`NeedsNetworkData` cannot fetch its own data*, there is no way to have a simpler implementation of what you did. you actually implemented the only way that available; further, you may just bind `network_data` to `test` property, allowing the `Loader` to detect the data arrival.

Comment: @SMR It doesn't matter if  `NeedsNetworkData` can or can't fetch its own data, the data can be fetched at the backend arbitrarily. The only requirement is that `NeedsNetworkData` can tell the parent `Item` when it is ready for render.

Comment: Since the only `Loader` is the only component that can delay components initialization and you have to pass properties imperatively this is not currently feasible.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a demonstration using Promises:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Pane {
    id: root
    Button{
        text: 'fetch'
        onClicked: {
            Promise.resolve()
            .then( () => setSource("Loading.qml") )
            .then( () => sleep(500) )
            .then( () => fetch( {  url: 'https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest?f=json' } ) )
            .then( (resp) => setSource("NeedsNetworkData.qml", {network_data: resp.responseText}) )
            ;
        }
    }
    Loader {
        id: loader
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: 250
        height: 250
    }
    Component {
        id: sleepComponent
        Timer {
            property var resolve
            running: true
            repeat: false
            onTriggered: {
                resolve();
                Qt.callLater(destroy);
            }
        }
    }
    function setSource(src, prop) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            if (prop)
                loader.setSource(src, prop);
            else
                loader.source = src;
            resolve();
        } );
    }
    function sleep(interval) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            try {
                sleepComponent.createObject(root, {
                    resolve: resolve,
                    interval: interval
} );
            } catch (err) {
                reject(err);
            }
        } );
    }
     function fetch(properties) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            let _prop = Object.assign({}, properties);
            let method = _prop["method"] ?? "GET";
            let url = _prop["url"] ?? "https://www.arcgis.com";
            let body = _prop["body"] ?? null;
            let headers = Object.assign({}, _prop["headers"]);
            let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xhr.readyState !== XMLHttpRequest.DONE) return;
                let responseJson = null;
                try {
                    responseJson = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                } catch (parseErr) {
                    console.error(xhr.responseText);
                    reject(parseErr);
                    return;
                }
                let obj = {
                    response: responseJson,
                    responseText: xhr.responseText
                };
                Qt.callLater(resolve, obj);
            };
            let _url = url;
            let payload = null;
            if (body) {
                let query = [ ];
                for (let key in body)
                    query.push(key + "=" + encodeURIComponent(body[key]));
                let queryString = query.join("&");
                payload = queryString;
                if (method === "GET") {
                    _url = url + "?" + queryString;
                    payload = null;
                }
            }
            xhr.open(method, _url);
            if (method !== "GET" && payload)
                headers["Content-type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            if (headers)
                for (let header in headers)
                    xhr.setRequestHeader(header, headers[header]);
            if (payload)
                xhr.send(payload);
            else
                xhr.send();
        } );
    }
}

// Loading.qml
import QtQuick
AnimatedImage {
    anchors.centerIn: parent;
    source: "https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.behance.net/project_modules/disp/04de2e31234507.564a1d23645bf.gif"
}

// NeedsNetworkData.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls

Rectangle {
    required property var network_data
    color: "grey"
    Text{
        anchors.centerIn:parent;
        text: network_data
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

Here's a demonstration on how to use `SequentialAnimation`, `ParallelAnimation`, `PauseAnimation` and `ScriptAction` to achieve a similar outcome. Unfortunately, we do not know how long the XMLHttpRequest will take, and, we cannot signal the ScriptAction on a delayed outcome, so, we have to increase duration in the `PauseAnimation` in hope that it will cover the `XMLHttpRequest` duration.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Pane {
    id: root
    property string network_data
    Button{
        text: 'fetch'
        onClicked: SequentialAnimation {
            ScriptAction {
                script: loader.source = "Loading.qml"
            }
            PauseAnimation {
                duration: 500
            }
            ParallelAnimation {
                ScriptAction {
                    script: {
                        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                        xhr.open('GET', 'https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest?f=pjson');
                        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                            if (xhr.readyState !== XMLHttpRequest.DONE) return;
                            network_data = xhr.responseText;
                        };
                        xhr.send();
                    }
                }
                PauseAnimation {
                    duration: 1000
                }
            }
            ScriptAction {
                script: loader.setSource("NeedsNetworkData.qml", {network_data});
            }
        }
    }
    Loader {
        id: loader
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: 250
        height: 250
    }
}

// Loading.qml
import QtQuick
AnimatedImage {
    anchors.centerIn: parent;
    source: "https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.behance.net/project_modules/disp/04de2e31234507.564a1d23645bf.gif"
}

// NeedsNetworkData.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls

Rectangle {
    required property var network_data
    color: "grey"
    Text{
        anchors.centerIn:parent;
        text: network_data
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

In both the Promise and SequentialAnimation cases, and, in general, the programming pattern you follow in your app is very personal and will require you to make a judgement call since such changes, unfortunately will stipulate a degree of consistency throughout your app. i.e. if you Promisify one area, it will cause you to Promisify other areas of your app. Similarly, if you use SequentialAnimation in one area, it will require you do similar throughout. Otherwise, you can use the signal/slot approach.

It all boils down to how you want to organize the business rules of your application.

Comment: Props for demonstrating that Promises can be used in QML. It's mentioned that it's supported [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-functionlist.html), but never used in any of their examples.

Comment: 1. This is very specific, can you make this reusable? 2.  I don't fetch data with JS is it done it the backend. 3. this is very imperative and [it is not considered best practice](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4qzPp8LwLz4)

Comment: 1. The way how sleep(), fetch() and setSource() are written is reusable. 2. XMLHttpRequest is functionality on par with QNetworkAccessManager, but, sure, if you want to wrap it as a QML component feel free to do so, 3. imperative vs declarative comes down to whether business rules are centeralized vs distributed. Plus, continuing on with our other comment, I have added how you may use PauseAnimation to solve this problem.

Comment: I appreciate the effort you made here, though your answer should have been "no there is no equivalent"  since what you did is very imperative and the promises game has no benefit here since you could just have a signal handler on QML for when data has arrived from the backend and call `Loader.setComponent`. the goal of `Suspense` is to **be** declarative, since you could do the same in react before `Suspense` with some property checks.

Comment: @ניר I see, I think I understand your concerns. I interpreted the OP's question as how to consolidate the business rule of "loading" in one location. Whereas, you interpreted the OP's question about how to show two components declaratively. Because we both do not entirely understand this NeedsNetworkData it's not possible to answer the question without translating that requirement to either XMLHttpRequest and/or QNetworkAccessManager.